# Strict Content Security Policy: unsafe-inline vs hash

Tags: content-security-policy

Slowly creating strict CSP and seeing any errors pop-up. Just need to add script-src, default-src and style-src. Each of these causes many-multiple errors each stating the same:

`* Refused to execute a script because its hash, its nonce, or 'unsafe-inline appears in neither the script-src directive nor the default-src directive of the Content Security Policy.`
`* Refused to apply a stylesheet because its hash, its nonce, or 'unsafe-inline' appears in neither the style-src directive nor the default-src directive of the Content Security Policy.`

But no further details are given in FireFox or Safari. I was thinking of using a hash, but can't see how without further details and possibly with so many errors.

*Is unsafe-inline okay to use? Or will it make the whole of the CSP (even those without unsafe-inline such as connect-src, media-src etc) pointless?*

*If I need to add unsafe-inline for these to work, would I be better not to add script, default and style to CSP?*

Current CSP Header:

`https://........cdn.net https://yoast.com; font-src 'self' https://........cdn.net data: fonts.gstatic.com; frame-ancestors 'self' https://........cdn.net; media-src 'self' https://........cdn.net; form-action 'self' https://........cdn.net; frame-src 'self' https://........cdn.net https://wwww.youtube-nocookie.com https://www.google.com/recaptcha/ https://recaptcha.google.com/recpatcha https://www.recpatcha.net; img-src 'self' https://........cdn.net http://www.w3.org data: image/svg+xml; style-src 'self' https://........cdn.net; default-src 'self' https://........cdn.net; script-src 'self' https://........cdn.net"`